# ubuntu extract multiple .tar.gz files to new directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have about 200,000 thumbs in a folder that are all gzipped ending with .tar.gz
What I am looking to do is extract all the files in that folder but to a different folder. Does anyone know a command to do this? I found this online but I wouldnt know how to use it to extract to a different folder.

```
for i in *.tar.gz; do tar -xvzf $i; done
```

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Comment: no idea but i found similar questions on here so i figured i would ask because there is lots of knowledge here.

Comment: Any questions similar to your would have been deleted or closed/migrated.

Comment: well now i know. i will no longer ask any questions that are not programming related. I dont see what the big deal is. I got my answer fast and that's what matters to me in the end but i will refrain from such questions now on.

Comment: @Chris: It's not necessarily a big deal, and I wasn't trying to blame you for doing something wrong. The issue is just that there are a lot of questions on Stack Overflow already, and the only way to keep that manageable is to limit the scope to programming issues. There are other sites in the network for [Unix/Linux questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), and even one specifically for issues with [Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). In the future, you might try one of those sites for non-programming-related questions. Cheers! And glad you got a quick answer.

Comment: ok thank you, I wasnt aware of those sites.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add the `-C` option to select the target directory:

```
for i in *.tar.gz; do tar xvzf $i -C path/to/output/directory; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Right now you are using

```
tar
```

to extract all the files. I believe that you can set which directory to output to.

It would be something like this:

```
for i in *.tar.gz; do tar -xvzf $i -C directory; done
```

where directory is the path of the folder you want to extract the files to.

Refer to http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utar.htm (documentation on tar).

Answer (score 2):

```
actdir=`pwd`
for files in *tar.gz ; do
  filedir=`basename $files .tar.gz`
  mkdir $filedir 
  cd $filedir
  tar -xzf ../$files
  cd $actdir
done
```

HTH

Comment: I'm impressed with the fact that tar doesn't have the option of creating the folder automatically. Thanks for your script, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The -C option is probably better. You could also do:

> $ mkdir /path/to/newfolder
>   $ for i in *.tar.gz; do files="$files $(readlink -f $i)"; done # builds absolute list of filenames
>   $ cd /path/to/newfolder
>   $ for i in $files; do tar -zxvf $i; done